# Getting Empty list in output

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, binary, list-comprehension

The prog is to accept 4 digit binary number separated by ','.
Then I have to print those number which is divisible by 3.

Here is my code

```
binary_numbers = input("Enter Binary Numbers:").split(",")

newlist = [no for no in binary_numbers if int(no)%3 == 0]
print(newlist)
```

when I am printing `newlist` I am getting empty. I dont know where is the problem.

Comment: You're interpreting the input as decimal.

Comment: what inputs are you giving?

Comment: Hi, I executed your code as it is, and I am getting expected outputs.
What inputs did you give?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to input binary numbers, you should set the base of the **int** cast to *2*.

```
[no for no in binary_numbers if int(no, 2) % 3 == 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
binary_numbers = input("Enter Binary Numbers:").split()
```

Comment: Where's the "divisible by 3" check?